# Compilation hangs when minted precedes istgame

Tags: compiling, minted, istgame

I can't get the following code to compile on my Windows machine after upgrading to TeX Live 2021. This used to work fine with TeX Live 2019.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage[outputdir=./.temp]{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{text}
    hello
\end{minted}

\begin{istgame}
    \istroot(0)
    \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

```sh
latexmk --output-directory=.temp -latexoption=--shell-escape test.tex
```

The log gets to this point, and then it hangs indefinitely

```
D:\test>set  /p x=D:\test\.venv\Scripts\pygmentize.exe 0<nul: 1>>test.aex

D:\test>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>test.aex

D:\test>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>test.aex
system returned with code 1
 (.temp/test.aux) (./.temp/_minted-test/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)
(./.temp/_minted-test/default.pygstyle)
(./.temp/_minted-test/437E267D5159CB3E1880E2F59933381F37A68874F7479A9FD91AC7B65
D4A9BC0.pygtex)
```

When I forcefully terminate it, the following is logged

```
!Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)
 Interruption.
\istownerstyle code ...owner@text@font \endcsname
                                                  {#1}\fi
l.14     \endist
              (.venv)
```

If I move the minted environment after the istgame one, then it works just fine. If I remove either the minted or istgame environment, it also starts to work. The order of `\usepackage` does not seem to matter.

I tried to reproduce this in a container using the `texlive/texlive:latest` image, but it compiles fine in there. I am at a loss for how to debug this further.

Comment: Try if it works if you remove the outputdir setting and compile without latexmk.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did that and ran `pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex`. It still hangs in the same manner.

Comment: well it worked for me. Is your texlive up-to-date?

Comment: Evidently it is not, despite just installing it yesterday. I have to wait for `tlmgr update --all` to finish, which is projected to take an hour (?!?), and then I'll report back.

Comment: Hangs for me in TeX Live 2020 with the same problem.

Comment: `tlmgr install istgame --reinstall`

Answer (score 1):

Hangs with TeX Live 2020 as indicated, but not with TeX Live 2021.

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{istgame}

\istownertextfont{@firstofone}% <----

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{text}
    hello
\end{minted}

\begin{istgame}
    \istroot(0)
    \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

But, really, `istgame` should ***not*** state `\istownertextfont{ }` with a space.

Comment: Updating TeX Live fixed my issue, so I'm not able to confirm whether your answer would have fixed it for me. Regardless, if you don't mind sharing, how'd you figure out this solution? I'd like to get better at that for LaTeX.

Comment: @bgfvdu3w I saw where the compiler hanged and looked at the definition of the `istgame` environment, finding the dubious space.

Comment: Oh, now I noticed that the log after I interrupt does hint at this. I don't think I'm ready to be diving into the source code of packages yet, so I feel a bit uneasy knowing that the compiler can hang like this with almost no feedback.

Comment: @bgfvdu3w I'm not sure what the problem is, but, as far as I can see, the code in `istgame` has some “peculiarities”.

Comment: @egreg (I only see this today.) I agree there is an issue with in `\istownertextfont { }`.  I will take care of this in a few days, including a few other things.